# iPhone Core Data get Grandchildren

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest

If I have entities set up for Parent - Child - Grandchild and one to many relations between them I know I can then get all the Child entities for a parent or all the Grandchild Entities for a Child.

Is it possible to run a fetch that will get all the Granchild entities for a given Parent?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without inverse relationships for each to-many relationship, no you cannot run a fetch request that you describe. However, you should be modeling the inverse relationships. CoreData uses the inverses to maintain consistency of the object graph. Given `parent` relationships from `Child` to `Parent` and `Grandchind` to `Child`, you can do

```
Pareint *aParent; //already initialized

NSSet *allGrandchildren = [aParent valueForKeyPath:@"children.@unionOfSets.children"];
```

or a fetch request on the `Grandchild` entity with predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parent.parent == %@", aParent];
```